# PayPal Integration and Sandbox Test Account Android

Tags: android, paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

I am developing Android App in which i have to integrate Paypal.i have followed [MPL PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/) tutorial to integrate PalPal in App.I understood it clearly.But my Problem is

1. I am unable to make personal and business test account because when i make account it ask me account details.
2. I am living in non-usa country.

i follow [SandBox TestAccount](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/#accounts) to make account.

**Problem Nob 1.** It says
[image]

when i go to paypal.com to make Test Account then

**Problem Nob 2.**

My country is not in the list of  "**Your country or region**"
[image]

**Problem Nob 3.**

When i go to make Individual Test Account then it ask me Credit Card Information

[image]

If i ignore Credit Card Information at this point then at next step i have to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From start

Go to

https://developer.paypal.com/

Create a new developer account and log in

there you can create a sandbox account you have two options

personal or bussiness account.

when you create a personal account an automatic credit card will be added to your paypal login.

by using this login details you can test your application.

Comment: hi am also plan to integrate pay pal Indian business account in android app.download pay pal android sdk and configure in libs and set build path.sand box testing is OK money transfers from accounts. How can add live business account details and generate client id and secrete.I need to integrate Indian pay pal business account for that what i need to use MPL.jar of Android SDK. When login to pay pal developer site one mail id ends with-facilitator as default business account.money transfers to that id.in that place how can i add my live details.